# How to customize wp_link_pages()?

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages

Does anyone know how to customize `wp_link_pages()` so that `<!--nextpage-->` will show like `"<< previous"` and `"next >>"` links instead of `"Pages: 1 2 3 "`?

Note:- i used `"<!--nextpage-->"` in my Wordpress tinymce editor for pagebreaks between long pages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `next_or_number` param of `wp_link_pages` to achieve this.

From [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages):

> **next_or_number**
>
> (string) Indicates whether page numbers should be
>   used. Valid values are:
>
> - number (Default)
> - next (Valid in WordPress 1.5 or after)

Then you can use `nextpagelink` and `previouspagelink` params to modify these links texts.

So doing it like this should do the job:

```
<?php
    wp_link_pages( array(
        'next_or_number' => 'next',
        'nextpagelink' => 'next &gt;&gt;',
        'previouspagelink' => '&lt;&lt; previous'
    ) );
?>
```